# Cannot relogin by ssh after rebooting Yocto Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, yocto-project

Prerequisite:

- HostPC(Windows) as client
- LinuxBoard(yocto linux) as server
- LinuxBoard eth0 already setting static IP from the start
- SSH connection via ethernet cable
- ssh_config on HostPC (C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_config)

  ```
  Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 5
    ServerAliveCountMax 20
  ```
- ssh_config on LinuxBoard is default

I have problem on re login after rebooting my LinuxBoard.
To reproduce the problem:

1. From HostPC(Windows) connect SSH to LinuxBoard(yocto linux)
   At first connection is success. Continue with login.
2. Then after login, reboot LinuxBoard by run `reboot`
   In this phase, ssh is disconnected.
3. I re login by run this command

```
C:\Users\evan-hutomo>ssh -vvv root@192.168.1.xxx
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/evan-hutomo/.ssh/config error:2
debug1: Reading configuration data __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_config
debug1: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.xxx [192.168.1.xxx] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000020A0B5516A0
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

I did not enough with ssh behavior, however I try to reconnect to LinuxBoard and sometimes I can connect, but mostly I cannot connect to LinuxBoard.
My goal here is to make Host able to re login to Server after rebooting.
I tried with several similar commands here but still gave me same phenomenon.
`reboot`, `shutdown -r`, `systemctl reboot`
I already search the result on SO, and everything but still did not solve my problem.

Could somebody give me insight to solve this phenomenon?

Thank you